# I'm unable to run the code through console of pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I just want to run the code through using console of pycharm.
But if I write "python tmp.py" in console,the below sentences are displayed.

```
File "<input>", line 1
python tmp.py           
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And the code which I want to run is below one.

```
def func(a):
    return a*a
n=int(input())
print(func(n))
```

Incidentally,it is able to run the code through terminal.
Please give me a solution for it.

Comment: Because you are running `python tmp.py` in the python interpreter, not in the terminal/console

Comment: I see.But I wrote that sentence at Python Console.What should I do?.

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running `python tmp.py` in the Python console tab (on the right). You should run it in the terminal tab (on the left)

[image]

Comment: Understood.And I succeeded to run the code.Thank you for your advice.